# Read whole text file into memory, then process it line-by-line without allocation/copy

Tags: c++, c++17, ifstream, stringstream, string-view

Suppose we've read the content of a text file into a `stringstream` via

```
std::ifstream file(filepath);
std::stringstream ss;
ss << file.rdbuf();
```

and now want to process the file line-by-line. This can be done via

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(ss, line);)
{
}
```

However, having in mind that `ss` contains the whole content of the file in an internal buffer (and that we can obtain this content as a `string` via `ss.str()`), the code above is highly inefficient. For each line of the file, a memory allocation and a copy operation is performed.

Is it possible to come up with a solution that provides the `line`s in form of a `std::string_view`? (Feel free to use an other mechanism to load the whole file; I don't need it to be accessed via a `stringstream`.)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex might be useful.

Comment: It's not  "highly inefficient" to do it that way.  This has been hashed over a lot.

Comment: What happens if there is not enough memory to hold the entire file in memory?

Comment: Does the program *really need* the entire file in memory at once?  Most programs read in data from the file and no longer use it; thus they can read in a record at a time.  Text editors are a different animal.

Comment: Search the internet for "memory mapped files".\

Comment: Or read `man 2 mmap`. (with C example provided)

Comment: You only create the `line` variable once, and then reuse it. What is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

> the code above is highly inefficient. For each line of the file, a memory allocation and a copy operation is performed.
>
> Is it possible to come up with a solution that provides the lines in form of a std::string_view?

No, as far I know.

But you can use the `getline()` method in `stringstream` that receive a pointer to a `char`.

Something as (caution: code not tested)

```
constexpr std::size_t dim { 100U }; // choose you the dim

char buff[dim];

while ( ss.getline(buff, dim) )
 {
   // do something
 }
```

The copy remain but, at least, this way you should avoid the -- for each line -- allocation.

Comment: `std::string` will also reuse its internal buffer and only reallocate if you get a line much longer than anyone seen before.